# syntax e34irror, unexpected '3rre 3rè24)

Tags: php

I have an issue when trying to reset the password in my WordPress template.

I receive the following error in the browser:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'From' (T_STRING) in /home/arasss/public_html/londynek/wp-content/themes/flatads/template-reset.php on line 48

Lines 29 to 63 below

```
if ( isset( $_POST['email'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) {

        // Next, sanitize the data
        $email_addr = trim( strip_tags( stripslashes( $_POST['email'] ) ) );

        $user = get_user_by( 'email', $email_addr );
        $user_ID = $user->ID;

        if( !empty($user_ID)) {

            $new_password = wp_generate_password( 12, false ); 

            if ( isset($new_password) ) {

                wp_set_password( $new_password, $user_ID );

                $message = "<?php _e( 'Check your email for new password.', 'agrg' ); ?>";

                $from = get_option('admin_email');
                $headers = '<?php _e( 'From:', 'agrg' ); ?> '.$from . "\r\n";
                $subject = "<?php _e( 'Password reset!', 'agrg' ); ?>";
                $msg = "<?php _e( 'Reset password.', 'agrg' ); ?>\n<?php _e( 'Your login details', 'agrg' ); ?>\n<?php _e( 'New Password:', 'agrg' ); ?> $new_password";
                wp_mail( $email_addr, $subject, $msg, $headers );

                $resetSuccess = 1;

            }

        }
```

Can you see anything wrong in the code?.

Regards

Comment: You can see the problem in code highlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On order to fix the PHP error you need to escape the `'` characters. Change this line:

```
$headers = '<?php _e( 'From:', 'agrg' ); ?> '.$from . "\r\n";
```

To this:

```
$headers = '<?php _e( \'From:\', \'agrg\' ); ?> '.$from . "\r\n";
```

That however will not make the code do what you might expect it to. What you might actually want to do is changing these lines:

```
$message = "<?php _e( 'Check your email for new password.', 'agrg' ); ?>";

$from = get_option('admin_email');
$headers = '<?php _e( 'From:', 'agrg' ); ?> '.$from . "\r\n";
$subject = "<?php _e( 'Password reset!', 'agrg' ); ?>";
$msg = "<?php _e( 'Reset password.', 'agrg' ); ?>\n<?php _e( 'Your login details', 'agrg' ); ?>\n<?php _e( 'New Password:', 'agrg' ); ?> $new_password";
wp_mail( $email_addr, $subject, $msg, $headers );
```

To the following:

```
$message = __( 'Check your email for new password.', 'agrg' );

$from = get_option('admin_email');
$headers = __( 'From:', 'agrg' ) . $from . "\r\n";
$subject = __( 'Password reset!', 'agrg' );
$msg = __( 'Reset password.', 'agrg' ) . __( 'Your login details', 'agrg' ) . "\n" . __( 'New Password:', 'agrg' ) . $new_password;
wp_mail( $email_addr, $subject, $msg, $headers );
```

In your script you used `_e()` which in Wordpress prints the translated input. Instead use `__()` to return the input.

Comment: Look carefully. OP is inside PHP, and is using `<?php` while still inside PHP; you're doing one of the same mistakes.

Comment: @Fred-ii- There's actually nothing wrong with using the PHP opening tag inside a variable - if you know what you are doing. Take a look at this: http://codepad.org/qZtME3da

Comment: Well, either you're right and Girish and Elian are wrong, or vice-versa. You'll need to elaborate on the "if you know what you're doing" part. What is OP trying to do, I couldn't be certain.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've updated my answer to fit a bit better.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot, this almost fixed the issue, however I'm not receiving email parameters correctly.

$msg = _e( 'Reset password.', 'agrg' ) . _e( 'Your login details', 'agrg' ) . "\n" . _e( 'New Password:', 'agrg' ) . $new_password;

the above is now displayed on the website rather than passed to email message.

Comment: @Casper André Casse I also noticed I receive the email without subject, the values is also being passed to the website rather than email. Do you have any advise for this? Much appreciated, Arek

Comment: @user3779410 That's because the `_e()` function in wordpress prints the input. Try replacing `_e()` with `__()`. I've updated the code in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Casper. This fixed the issue.

Best Regards,
Arek

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is wrong. You should not use `<?php` tags inside `php`

```
 $headers = '<?php _e( 'From:', 'agrg' ); ?> '.$from . "\r\n";
```

to

```
 $headers = _e( 'From:', 'agrg' ).$from . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Line 48 should be wrapped in double quotes as to not have mixup with it's content and you should open `<?php` at the beginning of your script, it's not needed again until you close it. I removed all the `<?php`'s.

```
   if ( isset( $_POST['email'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) {

        // Next, sanitize the data
        $email_addr = trim( strip_tags( stripslashes( $_POST['email'] ) ) );

        $user = get_user_by( 'email', $email_addr );
        $user_ID = $user->ID;

        if( !empty($user_ID)) {

            $new_password = wp_generate_password( 12, false );

            if ( isset($new_password) ) {

                wp_set_password( $new_password, $user_ID );

                $message = "_e( 'Check your email for new password.', 'agrg' );";

                $from = get_option('admin_email');
                $headers = "_e( 'From:', 'agrg' ); ".$from . "\r\n";
                        $subject = " _e( 'Password reset!', 'agrg' ); ";
                        $msg = "_e( 'Reset password.', 'agrg' ); \n _e( 'Your login details', 'agrg' );\n _e( 'New Password:', 'agrg' ); $new_password";
                        wp_mail( $email_addr, $subject, $msg, $headers );
                        $resetSuccess = 1;

                    }

                }
```